# Can't set the CAN baud rate to 500 Kbps for MINI M4 STM32 on Cube IDE

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus, stm32cubeide

I am currently using MINI M4 STM32, with an STM32F4RG15 MCU.
I am facing issues wherein I can't increase the CAN baud rate beyond 250 kbps. Whenever I try to change the parameters to set the baud rate to 500 kbps or even 1 Mbps, CAN stops working and no messages are sent on the bus from the STM32.

I have tried the following calculators and used all the bit timing parameters suggested by them,
however, none of them have worked:

1. http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/
2. MikroElectronica's CANculator

I am using the following bit timing parameters for 250 kbps:

- SJW: 1 Tq
- Prescaler: 4
- TS1: 13 Times
- TS2: 2 Times

This is the code I am using in the main function:

```
HAL_Init();
SystemClock_Config();

MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_CAN1_Init();
MX_ADC2_Init();
CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef header1;
CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef rxheader;
uint8_t rxdata[8];

int a;

HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1);
uint32_t mailbox1;

while (1) {
    uint8_t txdata[8];


    uint32_t mailbox1;
    header1.StdId = 32;
    header1.ExtId = 2;
    header1.DLC = 8;
    header1.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
    header1.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    header1.TransmitGlobalTime = ENABLE;
    uint16_t time= HAL_CAN_GetTxTimestamp(&hcan1,mailbox1);
    txdata[7]=time;

    HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &header1, txdata, &mailbox1);

}
```

Comment: So what's your clock before and after prescaling? That's very likely the problem here.

Comment: Also when you say "no messages are sent" is that something you verified with an oscilloscope? Because that doesn't make any sense. It would attempt to send, then get error frames etc if the baudrate doesn't match.

Comment: You say that you can't set the baud rate to 500K, but it seems more accurate from your description to say _"CAN stops working at baud rate of 500K"_ - which is not the same thing at all.  Is it possible your bus is incorrectly terminated and it is not a software problem at all but a signal integrity issue?

Answer (score 0):

For unable to receive any CAN message, you might need to check following points:

- Source clock for CAN module: What is your source and frequency? Without this, no one can help you check the bit timing.
- Output measurement between CANH and CANL by osciloscope Or you could measure the pin CAN-TX (before transceiver) with high speed logic analyzer. This is for checking if you have any error in calculating bit timing.

Additionally, please note that for STM32F4, the `BS1 = TS1 + 1`, `BS2 = TS2 + 1`. From your config for 250Kbps, if the clock source is 16MHz so you lost 2 tq for calculating the bit timing. So the actual clock is ~222kbps (correct me if the clock is not 16MHz). For slow speed, may be it is accepted by the device so you could transmit/receive message.

Comment: I am using an Arduino-compatible MCP2515 CAN module with a source clock of 8 MHz. When I configure the device to send messages at 250 kbps, I get a CAN waveform for the same on my oscilloscope. However, when it is configured to 500 kbps or above, I do not receive any such waveform. Also could you please clarify regarding the BS1=TS1+1 and BS2=TS2+1? I didn't quite grasp what you were trying to say.

Comment: BS1=TS1+1 and BS2=TS2+1 they are effective value for phase segment 1 and phase segment 2. Note that SJW is different with Sync Tq.

Comment: If you are not able to see the waveform, please check:
- Terminator resistor value
- Disconnect the arduino (measure without arduino)
Because it fail to transmit for few cycle, it will enter error state and will not transmit any more.

Comment: Oh Okay. So should account for that and use 12 and 1 as TS1 and TS2 for the lost tq?

Comment: Try to find which work best. Normally, if you don't know how to select best value just try (sync + T1)/(sync + T1 + T2) = 80%. This work for most normal case.

Comment: I have decided to change the clock to PLL, but the device doesn't work on PLL clock. Do you have any suggestions for the same?

Comment: clock source is not the matter

Comment: I am having the exact same problem - I didn't see this question when I searched, just noticed it now in the sidebar! I am running at 36MHz from the HSE clock and using 18tq (1/15/2). I get the arbitration lost flag on all my transmits. Check your TSR register to see what you get.